# MS Access 2007: Is it possible to get (using VBA or something similar) the selected row in open table or from open query results?

Tags: events, ms-access, vba, ms-office, ms-access-2007

the title to this question says it all, I am looking for a way to achieve this. Is it possible?

Also, if this wouldn't be achievable, are there maybe any other ways in which I can pass the user selected ID from a table / query to a form (i.e. opening the form is not a problem, using the hyperlink field, passing the value of what was clicked is the tricky part).

Thank you.

Comment: Have you run through the basic tutorials that come with Access? It seems like you're trying to do in code things that are done with Access objects that you can create with point and click, which suggests to me that you're really not adapting to the Access way of doing things (likely because of lack of familiarity).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It is generally considered poor practice to give users direct access to tables or the results of queries. You should generally build a form that either

1. contains a list with the results of the table/query, or
2. is a continuous form bound to the table/query

The user can then select which item they desire from the form, and the form can send that selection to the other form.

Comment: All that said, a table datasheet is an object that has a subset of the properties of a form object. So you can get a field value of the current row with `Screen.ActiveDatasheet!MyField` (where `MyField` is the name of the column whose value you're looking for).

Comment: Very true. Making a read-only datasheet can be a fast and dirty way to display data with sorting/filtering for free. I still wouldn't recommend it, though. A continuous subform with the necessary logic for customizing `OrderBy` and `FilterOn` expressions gives you far more control.

Answer (score -1):

In Excel you would capture the event SheetSelectionChange so just the short of it:

```
'Variable for trapping events in Excel application.
Private WithEvents mxlApp As Excel.Application  

Private Sub mxlApp_SheetSelectionChange(ByVal Sh As Object, ByVal Target As Range)
    'Do stuff here.
End Sub
```

I would think it would be something similar in Access. I haven't programmed in VBA for Access before, but it should be similar.

Here's some resources:

http://www.cpearson.com/excel/appevent.aspx

http://www.cpearson.com/excel/Events.aspx

Comment: No, Access is not like a spreadsheet, so this is not in any way a helpful answer.